# What to do about infrequent false credit judgement?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit

Over the last couple of years I have infrequently had a false credit judgement held against me.

Over a year ago I attempted to get a Car loan through a bank and they wouldn not give me the loan due to a $2600 outstanding judgement against me. I went to another bank and applied for a loan and it did not show up and I was able to get the loan.

I have since ran my annual credit report twice and the judgment did not show up. I also have a friend who is a loan officer at a bank recently do a soft pull on my credit and it also did not show up.

The next week I went in to apply for a home loan, from the same bank that my friend works at, and the $2600 judgement showed back up, and due to my small credit history they would not approve me for a loan.

After speaking with my family it turned out that my grandpa also received the exact same info on his credit report recently. Me, my father, and grandpa all have the same name. The credit judgement that was showing up was for another person with our name in another county.

What can I do to get this cleared up and not show up for me anymore.

Comment: did you check all three credit bureaus?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I guess that is another part of my question. In the credit reports that I have received, both from my friend and my annual credit reports, the judgement has not showed up. In my home loan it did show up. Is the bank that I applied with required to give me my credit information if they decline my application? I don't know which bureau is the one reporting it.

Comment: You can get a copy of your reports once a year for free. https://www.annualcreditreport.com

Comment: @mhoran_psprep that is my problem. I have already ran my credit report this year through that service and nothing has showed up. It is inconsistent when it decides to rear its head. Since I do not know what agency is reporting it, do I contact all 3? Also I don't know anything about the judgement aside the fact that it is not mine, it is for $2600, and it has showed up on both my father's, grandfather's, and now my credit report all within the last yuear

Comment: All I can suggest is, next time it shows up, ask which agency they got that information from so you can challenge it. If it's showing up on multiple individuals' credit reports, it is probably *NOT* the credit agencies but some other source of data -- and you want to know which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the United States if a credit report is used to evaluate your creditworthiness and that information results in an adverse credit decision then you are entitled to request an entire copy of that report from the **credit bureau** (you already knew this part).

Also in this situation, **the company that denied you** must tell you every place from which they received information on you. You will need this in writing.

Then bring this to the attention the company that is providing the inaccurate information (the credit bureau).

If 30 days goes by and:

- they are still reporting this false information about you
- they have not substantiated the claim
- you have all the documentation from above

then you will have course to sue them. You can file this in small claims court or use a specialized paralegal and they will quickly handle this, possibly with no fee.

Documentation of all of what I've said can be found at:  https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/pdf-0096-fair-credit-reporting-act.pdf